# How to get link to S3 object after Zapier auto uploads to bucket?

Tags: zapier

I've got a workflow in Zapier that takes an end-user's file upload sent via Typeform and saves it to an S3 bucket.  This works fine.  However, I would like to capture the link to that object that Zapier sends to S3 and use it in another action in the Zapier flow.

So, I would like to do the following in the Zap:

1. Trigger — New end-user entry via Typeform (web base form)
2. Action — Upload file content from Typeform upload field to S3 bucket
3. Action — Capture S3 object upload link and POST to custom endpoint URL.

Is it possible to capture the S3 link after Zapier handles the upload to the S3 bucket?

Comment: Does the output of the Upload step (step 2 above) not include a link to the newly-uploaded file?

Comment: @xavdid No, unfortunately it does not.  I had to just "devise" the name based on the root URL and bucket name, plus the file (key) name and then get the extension with Zapier's Text Formatter using the Split option and getting the last index of the split.

Answer (score 1):

Found a bit of a workaround for this

**Trigger** - New or Updated file in Amazon s3

**Action** - Text Formatter by Zapier.
Transform -> URL Encode
Values -> Input -> Name 
Convert Space to Plus -> True

**Action** - Outbound email
Here I just put the bucket URL in plain text and appended the output from the text formatter to the end

Works in my use case - hopefully should work across many more